# PHP Type Hinting is not working

Tags: php, closures, instance, type-hinting

I am trying to use Type Hinting feature in my app but something is not working correctly. I tried the following

```
define('PULSE_START', microtime(true));

require('../Pulse/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php');


$app = new Application();

$app->run();

$app->get('/404', function(Application $app)
{
    $app->error(404);
});
```

And instead of 404 output i got this

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to {closure}() must be an instance of Pulse\Core\Application, none given in E:\Server\xampp\htdocs\web\pulse\WWW\Index.php on line 23
```

I dont understand it, the Application class is a namespaced class (Pulse\Core\Application) but I have created an Alias, so I dont think thats the issue.

Comment: I think you have to type the whole class including the namespace when creating an instance of your class.

Comment: Still wont work, same error

Comment: Remove the type hint and var_dump($app); die(); and see what you get....

Comment: this is what i got object(Pulse\Core\Application)#1 (1) { ["values":protected]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: Show the piece of code inside ->get that actually calls your anon function.

Comment: That is a var_dump from inside the closure?

Comment: What is `Pulse`? Some framework/router or your own code?

Comment: @Orangepill no, if you remove type hinting and call var_dump from closure you will get NULL

Comment: @dev-null-dweller yea thats my framework

Comment: Look in the implementation of Application::get ... make sure that $this is being passed as the first argument of the anonymous function or use use like I specified in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the fact that `none` is being given as the passed in type value I'm thinking get isn't passing a parameter when using the closure.  To get $app into the closure you can `use` the application instead.

```
$app->get('/404', function() use ($app)
{
    $app->error(404);
});
```

And verify that your `get` method is passing `$this` as the first argument of the anonymous function.

Comment: this works, but i still dont understand why my code does not work.But since i can pass multiple variables in use, this will work fine for me.Thnx

Comment: @SilvioMarijic Show the code in Application::get and we can get to the bottom of it.

Comment: This is the code of of $app->get() method.It is basicly just passing parameters to the Route class and Route class is calling Router. `public function get($route, $action)
 {

  return Route::get($route, $action);

 }`

Comment: and in Route::get... you should have something along the lines of ... $route($this, $action)... since it is being called staticly from an application instance then $this will resolve to your application instance...But this will make it where your Route::get command can only be used from an application context which is probably not what you want.

Comment: You are better off using the `use` notation in the closure I think

Answer (score 1):

Typehinting does not work that way - it requires parameter to be of given type, but you have to create code that will adjust parameters passed to the closure for yourself. Very simple implementation of such smart arguments:

```php
class Application{
    private $args = array(); //possible arguments for closure
    public function __construct(){
        $this->args[] = $this;  //Application
        $this->args[] = new Request;
        $this->args[] = new Session;
        $this->args[] = new DataBase;       
    }
    public function get($function){
        $rf = new ReflectionFunction($function);
        $invokeArgs = array();
        foreach($rf->getParameters() as $param){
            $class = $param->getClass()->getName();
            foreach($this->args as $arg) {
                if(get_class($arg) == $class) { 
                    $invokeArgs[] = $arg;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return $rf->invokeArgs($invokeArgs);
    }
}

$app = new Application();
$app->get(function (Application $app){
    var_dump($app);
});
```